# Exchange 2010 sp3 RPC connectivity between separate physical sites

Tags: networking, firewall, exchange, exchange-2010, rpc

Good evening! I have installed Exchange 2010 a few times in my life but never in an environment like this. Please don't judge me for this architecture, it wasn't my idea! ;)

I have two physical sites - one is a sort-of hot backup for the other. Each site has an equally deployed set of Exchange 2010 server roles. Both sites are on the same AD domain and are replicating well. Both sites have full access to AD.

Each site has:

Server 1 - HUB/CAS
Server 2 - Mailbox
Server 3 - Mailbox

(edge role performed by security appliance, not part of this problem/question)

The sites are separated by Cisco ASA Firewalls

I have followed the instructions available almost everywhere online to statically assign to RPC ports for the dynamic range to each server: 59540, and 59541 for ExchangeRPC, ExchangeAB, and ExchangeIS. These are permitted through the firewalls. 135 is also permitted (as is 25 for e-mail transfers).

I can do some things but not others - for instance:

I can move mailboxes from site A to site B. I can send e-mail from site A to site B.

I cannot access a mailbox through OWA that is in Site A through Site B's CAS role (or vice-versa). I cannot get certificates in EMC or EMS (system cites an RPC error). I cannot build a DAG across all 4 mailbox servers as is required by the architecture I was given. I do have a replication network setup on the 4 mailbox servers.

I believe this to be an RPC problem as that is the error I generally get. Netstat shows many ports listening on each server in addition to the ones I statically configured. I'm assuming that the servers are still handing out ports in the dynamic rpc range but I could be misunderstanding this process.

What am I missing?  How do I get RPC to work only over those two ports (or a couple more)?  Our networking group will not open 1000 or 5000 ports for me.

Alternately - is there a way you can think-of that I can push RPC traffic over the replication network?  I could probably get them to add the replication network to my hub/cas servers.

Any help is appreciated - thank you!